# Make boost library public (visible) for any Visual Studio project or even file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I recently installed the boost library in my windows machine and compiled it for mingw64 and Visual Studio. Everything works fine if I have a Visual Studio solution and add boost to the "Additional Include Directories" for the compiler  and  "Additional Library Directories" for the linker. However this approach only works when I am developing within a "solution". I want boost library to be visible to all files I open in Visual Studio and Cmake project ( because there's no properties to be changes for a Cmake project). How can I do that.
For example, I just want to write :

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
```

and move on ..

Comment: I am somewhat confused. You are using mingw + CMake in Visual Studio Community?

Comment: If you are using CMake you should not touch the project properties in Visual Studio because the next time the project is generated your changes will be gone.

Comment: In CMake you need this: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) however remember that mingw binaries are not compatible with msvc so if you are using microsoft's compiler the find_boost() will require msvc binaries and not mingw

Comment: if you are talking about using Visual Studio's integrated CMake support then you need to set up your dependency on Boost the CMake way; that is, in your CMakeLists.txt file and then possibly help VS find the dependency using the CMakeSettings.json file, which can be edited from VS although this facility is kind of buggy/not ergonomic imo.